# Pulling individual objects/properties from variable (Powershell)

Tags: xml, powershell, variables

I'm currently storing AD user properties for multiple users in a variable. I need to then be able to pull out the individual properties to feed into an XML file. Right now I'm somewhat stuck as I don't know if I can pull out the individual properties. I know the code as I have it tries to populate all the properties for each user in each variable in the XML, but wanted to show the thought process. Is there a way to call the individual properties?

```
$base = 'ou=my users,dc=mydomain,dc=com'
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

$people = get-aduser -SearchBase $base -Filter {whencreated -gt $date} -Properties * | select name,emailaddress,title -OutVariable results

foreach ($result in $results){

$name = $results.name
$email = $results.email
$title = $results.title

$xmlfile=[xml] @"
<users><user><name>$name</name><email>$email</email><title>$title</title</user></users>
"@
```

Comment: Are you making one file for each user or multiple users in one file?

Comment: I think it could be accomplished either way. Ideally one xml file with multiple users to throw back at the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to find a way to use xml processes and methods as much as possible here to adhear to the proper methods of creating this file. Hopefully someone has a better approach but it gets the results I think you want.

```
# Base XML
$xml = [xml]@"
<users>
</users>
"@

# Template for creating nodes. 
$userTemplate = @"
<user>
    <name>{0}</name>
    <email>{1}</email>
    <title>{2}</title>
</user>
"@

$base = 'ou=my users,dc=mydomain,dc=com'
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

Get-ADUser -SearchBase $base -Filter {whencreated -gt $date} -Properties emailaddress,title | select name,emailaddress,title| ForEach-Object{
    # Create and append a child for each user
    $child = $xml.ImportNode(([xml]($userTemplate -f $_.Name,$_.emailaddress,$_.title)).DocumentElement,$true)
    $xml.documentelement.AppendChild($child) | Out-Null
}

# Should use your own path and a variable here. 
$xml.Save("c:\temp\text.xml")
```

Your saved file should now look like this:

```
<users>
  <user>
    <name>Matt</name>
    <email>address@mail.com</email>
    <title>Awesome</title>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>Michael</name>
    <email>address2@mail.com</email>
    <title>Guy</title>
  </user>
</users>
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt. That creates the xml file that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Will be much easier to do like this:

```
$base = 'ou=my users,dc=mydomain,dc=com'
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

$people = get-aduser -SearchBase $base -Filter {whencreated -gt $date} -Properties * | select name,emailaddress,title -OutVariable results

$xmlfile= $people | ConvertTo-Xml
```

Anyway your foreach section is wrong as well, you are calling `foreach ($result in $results)` which is not exist, your array called `$people`, also your `email` definition is wrong, should be `emailaddress`

```
foreach ($result in $people){

$name = $result.name
$email = $result.emailaddress
$title = $result.title

[xml]$xmlfile...
}
```

To get the InnerXml:

```
$xmlfile.InnerXml
```

Comment: `ConvertTo-Xml` won't give him the schema he is looking for. Unless that is acceptable

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The reason I didn't use ConvertTo-Xml was because the XML has to be in the format of my original post.